# Flutter widget not on top of each other , but next to each other

Tags: flutter, widget

does anyone how I can put the `Container()` next to the `Text()`? because if I do it like in the current code the two things are on top of each other. If anyone knows how to fix this comment please.

```dart
title:Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                      width: 3,
                      color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                    spreadRadius: 2, blurRadius: 10,
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                    offset: Offset(0,10),
                  ),
                  ],
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: NetworkImage("https://www.senertec.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png"),
                  )
              ),
            ),
            Text(widget.userName,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Orbitron',
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `Row()` widget? It is the same as a column but it is aligned horizontally!

Comment: that should be you using Row widget

Comment: Thankss!! Nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Row() instead of Column()